# Rollback database backup from magento 2.2.7 to 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, magento2.2.7

Is possible to rollback databse backup that is created on Magento 2.2.7 to Magento 2.3.0 ?

Thanks!

Comment: means? you have to upgrade before backup create?

Comment: I want to install fresh Magento 2.3.0 and import database from my current store wich is Magento 2.2.7.

Is that possible?